# Why is the meat of Sacrifice Wasted?

Tags: hajj, meat, sacrifice

What is the purpose of Sacrifice in Mina, whereas much of the sacrificial meat is not used properly and has to be buried?

Comment: i heard that it is sent to the starving people of poor countries.. not sure about it getting wasted

Answer (score 1):

Sacrifice in Mina (منا) is a symbol of what prophet Ibrahim (pbuh) had done and reminds us the story of sacrificing Ismael (the son of prophet Ibrahim) and also can be a symbol of sacrificing Nafs-al-ammarah (it means destroying the sins of our selves) and about this issue of lavishing such meats that completely comes back to Muslims management and planning for example we can give these meats to the poor.

Comment: it is a nice response, I should likewise mention that I've heard that recently, there are a place which make the meats as different packets and seemingly they will be sent to the poor countries. (as far as I know, it was a plan which Iran presented(and perhaps some other countries)